# Ubuntu 14.04 software update causes system failure and messed up graphics

Tags: grub2, updates, software-center

I allowed the software updater on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine to update various software packages today (1/25/2014).  A reset was requested.  I reset my machine and it now comes up with messed up graphics.  Upon boot, I get "error: no video mode activated".  The graphics appear quite large.  I am able to get through the login screen, but after that I'm stuck and cannot do anything.

Sometimes it comes up with a blank screen now.  I am not able to reliably get into the grub menu.  I'm not sure there's anything there that I can do anyway that will help.
I would rather not have to reinstall.

For your information, this is a new system.  It had been working well for almost a week until I did this software update.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I've been booting with the last stable config in order to work around it but I'd rather be booting with the latest config. Have you figured out a fix for it?